# Unable to build application with "compile with .NET Native tool chain" option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

First of all the biggest issue is that it seems I must use "compile with .NET Native tool chain" option. With out it I'm unable to pass verification with the following errors

```
◦API OpenSemaphore in api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for    this application type. System.Threading.dll calls this API.
◦API CreateSemaphore in api-ms-win-core-kernel32-legacy-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. System.Threading.dll calls this API.
◦API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. FileDownloader.exe calls this API.
◦API DllGetActivationFactory in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. FileDownloader.exe has an export that forwards to this API.
```

I found on other forums that this errors usually happen because the application is build without "compile with .NET Native tool chain" option.
   Unfortunately, I cannot build with that option either because of the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Cci.Immutable.Vector' to type 'Microsoft.Cci.IGenericTypeInstance'.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?
Thank you

Alex

Comment: Did you use PInvoke in your app and used some Win32 API?

Comment: I use PInvoke in a few places but I didn't call OpenSemaphore or CreateSemaphore or ExecuteAssembly or DllGetActivationFactory. 100% sure, double checked. As I mentioned I found suggestions to use  "compile with .NET Native tool chain" option but it didn't work because of an error in the ILC tool.